# How to get the floating-unit-points from the volume?

Tags: python, volumetrics

I'm wondering about how to get the xyz grid volume units of an mesh object.

For example, a cube o' 1x1x1 valued on 1 blender unit, that would be 1cm x 1cm x 1cm would had measures o' 10mm x 10mm x 10mm and a 1mmx1mmx1mm could represent a voxel-unit.

My minimum unit size on blender is 0.000022.

What kind of code should be use to locate the density of every volumetrical point unit of a cube o' - for example - 1x1x1 blender units?

I think the most proper answer optionally would be "trying to find how many voxels of a given size would fit in a mesh" also having control of each voxel likewise a voxel in coordinates 0,0,0 and 0,1,1. I'm trying to make something like "A Boy and His Atom: The World's Smallest Movie" but with volumetric units as a display for specific physical equations. Similar to the idea o' Mandelbulb - JonasDichelle that displays an equation directly to a volume shader. It's possible however to get the floating-points units xyz properties coordinates?

I'm thinking something like procedural volumetrics from python code equations. The intentional purpose is to simulate the formulational equations of physics, to turn an equation into python code and turn it visible in space points of volumetrical units.
_

For example, if the variable e represents an electron with defined
physical properties ocurring in xyz+mt (m= movement | t= time), then a volumetric unit point - for example the volume of the whole scene starting from the world origin - would visualize the python code with the physical variables, for example, in a cubical grid of 10x10x10 the point z1y1x1 represents a cubical unit within the grid. How is it possible to retrieve the point unit into code so to attribute it to the variable e?

ref:Similar to this led cube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciaFar8nfHc&t=994s by being able to send a code to every volumetric point as a display

Comment: Are you trying to figure out something related to floating point precision or are you trying to find how many voxels of a given size would fit in a mesh or what?

Comment: I think the most proper answer optionally would be "trying to find how many voxels of a given size would fit in a mesh" also having control of each voxel likewise a voxel in coordinates 0,0,0 and 0,1,1. I'm trying to make something like "A Boy and His Atom: The World's Smallest Movie" but with volumetric units as a display for specific physical equations. Similar to the idea o' Mandelbulb - JonasDichelle that displays an equation directly to a volume shader. It's possible however to get the floating-points units xyz properties coordinates?

Comment: I'm thinking something like procedural volumetrics from python code equations

Comment: Thanks for the additional details! Would you mind editing your question to describe your ultimate goals a little bit and possibly improve the overall conciseness? I'm sure you'll be much more likely to get an answer with improved clarity.

Comment: Proving a particular algorithm is the most performant in packing cubes into an arbitrary mesh may be very hard, but if you impose alignment to grid, then remesh modifier + calculating volume should be able to do the work?

Answer (score 0):

[Setting Voxel Coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/setting-voxel-coordinates?rq=1)

Similar to this idea, where the coordinates o' xyz and density are saved in a file like xx yy zz dd

However this ocurring within a file is it possible to translate it into code for casting volumetrics from a script?